# AutoCorrect encoding regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, encoding, pattern-matching

I am building auto correct for string input encoding. And I want to build a regex for encoding pattern.

For example:

```
var encoding = "utd-8";
Correct c = new Correct(encoding);
var c.Correct();
```

And the output is `utf-8`.
I have most of the work (and using some open source coding from some great people that wrote beautiful stuff). Can some one help please?

**UPDATE**

What I need in the end is the regex pattern for the right encoding. 
The user input a encoding name `iso-8859-1` and it check if its valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't decide on which technology to use before you have figured out how to solve the problem; are Regular Expressions really necessary?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check whether the input string looks alot like one of the supported encodings. Before writing a single line of code, you'll have to figure out:

- Which encodings are you supporting? Are you supporting aliases (`UTF-16` is the same as `Unicode`)?
- How much is the input string allowed to be different from the chosen encoding (utd-8, utd-9, utd9, td9, 9)?
- Given the input string "utf-36", would the output be `UTF-16` or `UTF-32`?

Perhaps you can take a look at one of the string distance algorithms (for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for inspiration on the subject. There are a ton of links in the "see also" section there.

Comment: Also, supply the `encoding` variable as a parameter to the method, not to the constructor of the object. That way one `Correct` instance can correct multiple encodings. Or make the method static.

Comment: what i have to do is auto correct string input, in this case is some kind of encoding (i don't care to use really the encoding function its just an name to me) sorry if i wasn't understood.

Comment: so does the input string "utf-36" get auto-corrected to "utf-16" or "utf-32"? What would the string "xkueukr" be auto-corrected to? You can't tell 'puter to make these decisions for you

Comment: "puter" ? can you tell me what this is please ?

Comment: `'puter` should auto-correct to "computer". What about "utf-36"? Or "xkueukr"?

Comment: if it fails , it will get a default string of some sort like unknown or utf-8,

Comment: I'm getting the feeling you don't know exactly what you want your application to do. As soon as you answer my question, I _may_ be able to help you out (given that you understand the relationship between your problem and the link I posted).

Comment: sorry for me being not understandable, in the end i have an input string, which represent a name of encoding. i have to figure it out if the input is a valid encoding name, if no try and fix it as much as i can, if failed to correct the input return `Fail` or some default encoding name.

Comment: I think I understand what you want completely. You just need to decide HOW you want to fix the name. The wikipedia link I mentioned does just that - it calculates how much the input looks like a string. Do that for all strings, and you know which is the best match.

Comment: PS. If you like movies better than theory, and don't mind the french accent, have a look at this movie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUSqwTC8TM8